# Missing plug-ins for playing music and video in open SUSE?

Tags: music, opensuse

I use open SUSE but I can't get it to play music or vidoes, I have installed its drivers but I get this error " You don't have the plug-ins to do this " .

Comment: Which application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the codecs & plugins via the 1-click installer [from here](http://opensuse-community.org/1-click-collection).